# Why do TV subtitles use spaces (instead of commas)?

Tags: orthography

It looks like Japanese text don't use spaces between words, not even in informal messages (yes perhaps in textbooks, but I digress). [This page](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061231170308AAI1wdm) claims that a sentence with spaces inbetween just looks weird, example:

> 私の名前は ゆかです。

But it seems like Japanese subtitles in Jdramas / animes etc use spaces, not just once or twice, but *all the time*.

On the contrary, [the comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Comma) `、` is almost non-existent. It's almost as if each comma in a subtitle is replaced with a space instead.

I'm using the subtitles posted on d-addicts as an example. Out of [over 2000 Japanese sub files](http://d-addicts.com/forum/subtitles.php#Japanese), only roughly ~5%* contain the `、` character. In some files, the comma actually only appeared **once** or twice.

Some threads like [東野圭吾](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_96298.htm) and [秘密諜報員 エリカ](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_99994.htm) did not state the original source of the subtitles, but others like [医龍 3](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_89677.htm) and [ちりとてちん](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_58083.htm) do claim to have the subtitles extracted from the TV broadcast:

> These subtitles were extracted from the **corresponding TV broadcast**. **Text wasn’t edited in any way**. Due to some technical reasons there might be several missing characters and/or lines. Timing is not perfect but still good (at least not worse than original timing for TV).

D-addicts' examples of using spaces instead of comma:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Anime mkv files also have "built-in" subs using spaces instead of comma, for example the movie [Mugiwara Chase](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=F0iv1cgUUlI#t=182s):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is it that instead of using commas, Japanese subtitles use spaces instead?

What is the reason for this oddity?

==

*List of d-addict files with comma:

- [１リットルの涙 # 1-2](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_90851.htm)
- [1 Litre of Tears # 8](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_99358.htm)
- [Aishiteru # 1](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_76066.htm)
- [Ashita no Kita Yoshio # 11](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_59493.htm)
- [Atami no Sousakan # 3](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_87274.htm)
- [Bara no nai Hanaya # 1-4](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_68822.htm)
- [BOSS # 4-8](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_97214.htm)
- [Buzzer Beat # 11](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_78664.htm)
- [Cat Street # 1-5](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_65959.htm)
- [Celeb to Binbo Taro # 7](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_66431.htm)
- [Fuyu no Sakura # 9](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_92218.htm)
- [Gakko ja Oshierarenai! #2](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_63439.htm)
- [GM Odore Doctor # 9](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_87317.htm)
- [Gokusen 3rd ep06, # 8](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_60699.htm)
- [Haken no Hinkaku # 1](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_79182.htm)
- [Hanayome no Chichi # SP](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_103652.htm)
- [Hayami san to Yobareru Hi # 2](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_103887.htm)
- [Honboshi ~ Shinri Tokuso Jikenbo # 2](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_92302.htm)
- [Innocent Love # 3](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_66556.htm)
- [Isshun no Kaze ni Nare # SP part 3](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_58749.htm)
- [Kaeru no Ojou sama # 4, 5](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_108681.htm)
- [Kamen Rider Double # 1-17](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_78714.htm)
- [Kansahojin # 5](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_62711.htm)
- [Keibuho Yabe Kenzo # 4, 5](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_84619.htm)
- [Kimi Hannin Janai yo ne # 8](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_61990.htm)
- [Koukousei Restaurant # 5](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_95387.htm)
- [Kurumi no Heya # 1-6](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_97654.htm)
- [Last Friends # 8](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_61948.htm)
- [Last Money ~Ai no Nedan~ # 1](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_99291.htm)
- [Lost Time Life # 1](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_70114.htm)
- [Lotto 6 de 3 oku 2 senman En Ateta Otoko # 5](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_63031.htm)
- [Maou # 5, 11](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_63045.htm)
- [Marumo no Okite # 4](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_95017.htm)
- [Monster Parent # 1](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_63178.htm)
- [Nanase Futatabi # 8](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_66434.htm)
- [Nihongo de Kurasou # 1](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_13551.htm)
- [Nihonjin no Shiranai Nihongo # 1-2](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_86915.htm)
- [Nemureru Mori # 1-12](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_61092.htm)
- [Ohitorisama # 7](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_79035.htm)
- [Ohsama_no_resutoran # 1-3](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_50892.htm)
- [Orthros no Inu # 1-3, 5, 8-9](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_88507.htm)
- [Piece Vote # 6](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_97146.htm)
- [Ryoukiteki Na Kanojo # 4-5](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_65298.htm)
- [Saigo no Kizuna](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_98303.htm)
- [Shanghai Typhoon # 4](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_66211.htm)
- [Shikaotoko Aoniyoshi # 1-2](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_58086.htm)
- [Soredemo, Ikite Yuku # 6](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_96972.htm)
- [Stand Up!! # 7](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_85718.htm)
- [Sunao ni Narenakute # 4](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_84307.htm)
- [Tenshi no Wakemae # 1-3](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_86828.htm)
- [Tomorrow # 8-10](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_65182.htm)
- [Umareru # 10](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_95397.htm)
- [Unfair the special ~Double Meaning Nijuu Teigi](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_99534.htm)
- [Zettai Kareshi # 5-6](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_61720.htm)
- [デカ黒川鈴木 # 4](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_103629.htm)
- [MR. BRAIN # 6-8](http://www.d-addicts.com/forum/viewtopic_74874.htm)

Comment: (1) What is Jdrama?  (2) It is a long time since I watched a movie or a TV program with Japanese subtitles, but I think that the use of spaces is rare and that 読点 (、) is much more common except for subtitles for song lyrics.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Japanese TV drama, most of them I downloaded online (e.g. [d-addicts](http://d-addicts.com/forum/subtitles.php#Japanese)). Also some anime video files which are in .mkv format has built in  subtitles which looks like they are from the original producer.

Comment: I disagree with your observation, and agree with Tsuyoshi Ito's. You may want to add examples to make clear what you mean.

Comment: It is hard for me to imagine that the original producer of a Japanese TV series or anime adds Japanese subtitle to it.  (If they do that, who is the target audience?)

Comment: @sawa Ok I've edited the question to add some examples.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Not quite sure myself, but for example people that have hearing problems, or kids etc, and besides it'll benefit those mega screens fixed onto buildings because people don't really get access to the audio part.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I think you might be surprised by how many Japanese TV shows have subtitles (in Japanese) these days. Look for the little 字-in-a-box symbols in a TV guide, like this one: http://www.tbs.co.jp/tv/daily/?20120529 .

Comment: Incidentally, I do not know if Pacerier's subtitles were actually added by the producer, but I can vouch for having seen similar orthography watching live Japanese TV with the subtitles on. I am less confident about having seen spaces after は and so on, but I have definitely seen spaces after ねえ, あたし, etc. (basically corresponding to pauses in speech).

Comment: If Paceirer's subtitles are all from D-Addicts, then they were extracted from the original broadcasts' transport stream. They are intended for people who are hard of hearing, so you'll see things like `バイブレーターの音` and `ドアベルの音` to help people understand what's going on. That site uses them to help the translators work more quickly instead of by ear, or instead of going from Eng->Spa and such, and some use them to study.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not terribly concerned over this question, but it seems like a lot of effort was put into finding examples for/against the theory. So +1 from me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are right. There is an old rule in the industry to substitute [半角]{はんかく}スペース for [読点]{とうてん} and [全角]{ぜんかく}スペース for [句点]{くてん}. 半角スペース are counted as 0.5 spaces and 全角スペース are counted as 1 space respectively. However, television shows are less strict than movies and generally only omit 読点 only, whereas movies omit both.

> So, why is there this rule?

I think there are several reasons why. First, I think it should be noted that [句読点]{くとうてん} were not originally part of the Japanese language to begin with. There use originally started when text was being translated from other languages, such as English to Japanese in the Meiji Era. If you look at any old Japanese text before this you will probably not see there use. Some sites I have read point out this fact and claim that this "leftover tradition" is the reason why 句読点 are not used. However, there also is a strong notion that subtitles are [邪魔]{じゃま} and should only be used sparingly. Most companies have a rule that only allows up to 12 to 16 characters per line and a maximum of only 4 characters per second. Because of these restrictions, any extraneous stuff is left out. Also, some people claim that omitting 句読点 makes it easier to read without them and a lot of Japanese people don't use them to begin with.

By the way, +1 from me for a very nice observation :).

Comment: Cool =) so before the invention of punctuation, words are separated using only spaces?

Comment: @Pacerier: They probably weren't seperated at all. I thought even the period was a reasonably recent addition to Japanese. This is starting to stray well into the territory of 'this should be another question'.