# Need help translating 「俺が威嚇射撃する ゴーを出したら 突入だ」

Tags: colloquial-language

《俺が威嚇射撃する   ゴーを出したら   突入だ》

I will fire a warning shot, when GO begins  (must) rush in.
*My shot at figuring out a translation above.*

I figure it's something like, I will fire the warning shot, then say go, then we proceed, which is what happens next in the show.  Just now seeing how it all connects grammatically.

Edit:

《瀬文隊長が威嚇射撃後 ゴーの合図で突入します》is spoken right before they go in by another officer.  From that it's clear that:

After the commanding officer fires some warning shots, on the signal "go", we storm in.

Comment: Do you have question in there somewhere?

Comment: yeah sorry, trying to come up with a translation that makes sense.

Comment: I think your last translation was correct. I'd interpret 《俺が威嚇射撃する ゴーを出したら 突入だ》 as "I'll fire a warning shot. When I give the signal to go, we'll storm in"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to break this apart a bit:

- > 俺が威嚇射撃する

  "I will fire a warning shot."
- > ゴーを出したら

  "when (I) give the signal to go" (note the `を` which points to an implicit subject, here which I think is almost certainly "I". Also note the second definition at Daijirin for [`ゴー`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%82%B4%E3%83%BC&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0): `「進め」の信号。` or "a signal of 'advance!'")
- > 突入だ

  "it's storming in" (where `突入` is a noun), which I don't think you can directly translate into English but I think has the meaning of "we'll storm in" in this context.

I don't think that `威嚇射撃するゴー` could work, as that'd be "the go (signal) that warning shots", so I think there is an implied `。` where the space is, as is fairly common in manga and in many subtitles etc (see also [Why do TV subtitles use spaces (instead of commas)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5669/why-do-tv-subtitles-use-spaces-instead-of-commas) for an example of how punctuation can be omitted). So putting it all together:

> 《俺が威嚇射撃する ゴーを出したら 突入だ》
>   "I'll fire a warning shot. When I give the signal to go, we'll storm in"

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Has to be two separate sentences.  Arigatou

Comment: どうもありがとう[?＿?、?]大変勉強になりました。